# How to add additional parameters request url postman

Tags: json, url, postman, url-parameters

I have a request URL, in which I want to filter JSON data , postman

```
https://x.x.x.x/apiBlaBla/
```

returns

```
{
"resource:resource": {
"resource_name": "csp-2100",
"ip_address": "x.x.x.x",
"name":"host_name_1",
"location":"location_1"
}
}
```

When I do

```
https://x.x.x.x/apiBlaBla/name
```

return

```
{
"resource:name": "host_name_1"
}
```

I want to add an additional parameter to the URL to return Name and Location

I tried

```
https://x.x.x.x/apiBlaBla/name/location
```

which is not work

any suggestions on how to pass additional parameters, please

Thanks
R

Comment: Check the documentation of the service. The service must support multiple path params; which in your case does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Adding additional parameters in Postman doesn't extend the internal implementation/functionality of the API. It needs to support that first.